# How to NSLog calling function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nslog

Not the function calling the NSLog or Dlog but function that call that function.

I created a class

```
+(void) computeTime:(void (^)())block
{
    NSDate * currentTime = [NSDate date];
    block();
    DLog ("Time Running is: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:currentTime);
}
```

So everytime there is an operation whose time I want to measure I will put that in a block instead.

and do [Tools computeTime:^{//operation}];

However, I want to know the function that call that computeTime. How do I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options:

The first is to abuse `+[NSThread callStackSymbols]` to get an array of all the symbols in the call stack and pull out the one you want. I suspect this is going to be relatively slow.

The second is to use a macro. The C preprocessor provides a nice macro called `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` which contains the name of the function all nicely formatted, and it works well for Obj-C methods as well. Instead of `[Tools computeTime:^{/*operation*/}]` you can either use something like `[Tools computeTimeWithName:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ block:^{/*operation*/}]` or you could wrap it all up in your own macro so you can say `TOOLS_COMPUTE_TIME(^{/*operation*/})`:

```
#define TOOLS_COMPUTE_TIME(...) [Tools computeTimeWithName:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ block:(__VA_ARGS__)]
```

Note, I've used a varargs-style macro because the C Preprocessor doesn't understand obj-c syntax very well, so any commas inside your block will be interpreted as separate arguments to the macro. If I defined it using `TOOLS_COMPUTE_TIME(op)` then the compiler would complain that the macro only takes 1 argument but it was given multiple. By using varargs the compiler doesn't care how many arguments you give it, and it will pass them all on to the `__VA_ARGS__` token.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible answer for someone searching for the OP's original question and adding to Kevin's first suggestion to use the call stack.

If you're looking for what called a function (method), consider the following:

```
 NSArray *callStack = [NSThread callStackSymbols];
 // Top of the stack. Current method
 NSLog(@"Current method: %@", [callStack objectAtIndex:0]);
 // Called by
 NSLog(@"called by: %@", [callStack objectAtIndex:1]);
```

It is possible that the stack item looked for is further into stackArray.

Hope this helps find a bug quicker.